# How to make the 'breadcrumb' variable available in breadcrumb.html.twig available in node--type.html.twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

There's a variable `breadcrumb` that is available in breadcrumb.html.twig

I have a node type `Page` on which I need the breadcrumb, because it has to go in between my content.

The variable `breadcrumb` is not available on `node--page.html.twig` though.

How do I get it there?

I know this is done in the preprocess function/hook something somewhere, but I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the Twig Tweak module for this.
Which allows to place blocks anywhere you want in twig.

Answer (score 5):

If you have twig_tweak module enabled:

```
{{ drupal_block('system_breadcrumb_block') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please change your file name `node--page.html.twig` to `page--node.html.twig` then the `breadcrumb` variable is worked.
Try like this way.

```
{{ page.breadcrumb }}
```

it may be helpful for you.

Thanks

Comment: Eh? No? I need the node twig, not the page twig!